# I want to insert data from an Excel into an Access mdb (this works already) later I want to update rows in the mdb with new information

Tags: sql, vba, excel, ms-access

I have an Excel file with four columns which are named Feld1, Feld2, Feld3, Feld4.

Excel table example:
[image: Excel table example]

Now I want to send this data (only Feld1,Feld2Feld3) via a button to an Access mdb which I can do with the following code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
  Dim objRS As Object
  Set objRS = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
  objRS.Open "INSERT INTO Tabelle1 SELECT Feld1,Feld2,Feld3 FROM [Tabelle1$] IN '" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & "' 'Excel 8.0;'", _
      "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & "c:\ExcelToAccess.mdb"
  Set objRS = Nothing
End Sub
```

This works so far without any problems.

Now, I want to add the information in column "Feld4" (think of "Feld4" getting the data entered at a later time) later with an UPDATE sql, but unfortunately I have no idea about syntax etc., I just can't get it to work.

Basically the UPDATE sql should look WHERE Feld1+Feld2 match together and then update Feld4 in that same row.

Comment: Does Tabelle1 contain Feld4 (s/sheet and table)?  It would be `INSERT INTO Tabelle1 SELECT Feld4 FROM [Tabelle1$] IN .....` then `WHERE (Feld1+Feld2)=Feld4`

Comment: I think I misunderstood.  You'll need `UPDATE` look at http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp

Answer (score 0):

The following query is based on the fact that when Feld1 = Feld2, then Feld4 takes the value of Feld3.

```
update Tabelle1 set Feld4 = Feld3 where Feld1=Feld2;
```

Hope this can help!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, thank's for the inputs. With those inputs I found a way to do what I want. To make it easier I defined variables first and I also found the right way to write the syntax ;-)

This is what I came up with:

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

  Dim objRS As Object
  Set objRS = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

  Dim Feld1 As Long
  Dim Feld2 As Long
  Dim Feld3 As Long
  Dim Feld4 As String
  Feld4 = Worksheets("Tabelle1").Cells(3, "D").Value
  MsgBox Feld4
  Feld1 = Worksheets("Tabelle1").Cells(3, "A").Value
  Feld2 = Worksheets("Tabelle1").Cells(3, "B").Value

  objRS.Open "UPDATE Tabelle1 SET Feld4=""" & Feld4 & """ WHERE Feld1=""" & Feld1 & """ AND Feld2=""" & Feld2 & """", _
      "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & "C:\Users\icean\Google Drive\MyDocuments\AWA\ExcelToAccess.mdb"

  Set objRS = Nothing


End Sub
```

Of course, this is all just a "proof of concept". The real Excel and database I will amend tomorrow, but that's how it's going to work.